# physicsbodies don't seem to match the objects

Tags: game-physics, blender, scenekit

I've designed a level in blender made out of cubes to form a long hallway with rooms appearing on either side, but when I loaded it into scene kit, things didn't seem to match.  The floor of the hallway extends its entire length, but the physics body doesn't seem to fit it.  At the end of the hallway there is still a floor, but if the player walks on it, he will just fall right through. Some of the spaces between the walls (the doors) act like solid objects that the player can't walk through.  And at one point, I attempted to walk over an edge, but despite there being no floor, the scene acted as if I was still on solid ground for quite a while before I finally found the end of the physics body.
     While in Blender, I set the position of each object to be 0,0,0 and the scale to be 1,1,1 by applying object transformations so that it would be easier to work with when I brought them over.
     Is there a way to fix this issue or see physics bodies in scene kit so I can figure out what's going on?

```
 let Scene2: SCNScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/hallway.dae")!
    var nodeArray = Scene2.rootNode.childNodes
    var node = SCNNode()
    for childNode in nodeArray {
        println(childNode.position.z)
        var cN = childNode as SCNNode
        cN.scale = SCNVector3Make(cN.scale.x * 150, cN.scale.y * 150, cN.scale.z * 150)
            cN.position = SCNVector3Make(cN.position.x, cN.position.y, cN.position.z)
            cN.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Static, shape: nil)
            cN.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = rockCategory
            cN.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 3
             node.addChildNode(cN)
        if( childNode.name == "BackWall"){
            backWallLoc = SCNVector3Make(cN.position.x, cN.position.y, cN.position.z)
            println(backWallLoc.y)
        }
    }
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

Comment: I only know SK but it's pretty much the same with most physics engines: 1) scale does not apply to physics bodies 2) anchor/pivot point changes are not reflected in physics bodies (1&2 are visual-only properties the physics engine doesn't care about) 3) enable physics debug drawing if you suspect the bodies are "off"

Comment: i thought scale didn't work with physics bodies only if the scale was applied after the physics body was established